# How to prevent http.ListenAndServe altering style attributes in static output?

Tags: http, go

In a very rudimentary handwritten web page (no js, stylesheets, etc) I have some static html with a section that looks like this.

```
<li style="font-size:200%; margin-bottom:3vh;">
  <a href="http://192.168.1.122:8000">
    Reload HMI
  </a>
</li>
```

I'm using Go's http.ListenAndServe to serve the page. What's coming out looks like this:

```
<li style="font-size:200%!;(MISSING) margin-bottom:3vh;">
  <a href="http://192.168.1.122:8000">
    Reload HMI
  </a>
</li>
```

Note the altered style attribute.

The server implementation is also rudimentary. It's launched as a goroutine:

```
// systemControlService provides pages on localhost:8003 that
// allow reboots, shutdowns and restoring configurations.
func systemControlService() {
    info("Launching system control service")
    http.HandleFunc("/", controlPage)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8003", nil))
}

// loadPage serves the page named by title
func loadPage(title string) ([]byte, error) {
    filename := "__html__/" + title + ".html"
    info(filename + " requested")
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        info(fmt.Sprintf("error reading file: %v", err))
        return nil, err
    }
    info(string(content))
    return content, nil
}

// controlPage serves controlpage.html
func controlPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p, _ := loadPage("controlpage")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(p))
}
```

In func `loadPage()` above, `info` is a logging call. For debug, I'm calling it just before returning the content of `controlpage.html`. The log entry shows it's not mangled at that point, so the problem pretty much has to be within ListenAndServe.

I'm not finding anything in the Go docs for `http` that seems applicable. I have no idea what's going on here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can you try this, note **Fprint** rather than **Fprintf**

```
func controlPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p, _ := loadPage("controlpage")
    fmt.Fprint(w, string(p))
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I appreciate the concise solution and the lack of judgmental commentary. Thanks!

Comment: Why convert it to a string and use `Fprint`, when you could just call `Write`?

Comment: @JimB, yes that's probably better, though I'm not worried about optimization.  This is a last resort page on a small control system that serves to single touchscreen.

Comment: Why down vote? Do I pinpoint wrong line of error? I'm trying to make a simple answer as possible, nothing in the original question ask for optimizing the code.

Comment: I'm agree that my answer come with zero explanation, but the owner can easily determine the different between two functions. He maybe noticed that by himself. And if more explanation needed anyone can suggest editing or by comment, right?

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was precisely what I needed to spot the problem and fix it.  I disagree strongly with the downvotes.  Other answers have veered toward an unrequested code review -- informative but not what I was looking for. I simply got careless adapting from the Go http tutorial and hit one of those mental traps where I overlooked the obvious.

Comment: @MikeEllis: sorry, but this site is not for your personal benefit, it intended to be a resource where anyone can find community vetted reference material. The other answer is more correct, and serves the purpose of teaching others much better.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems with your code (including the fact that it exists at all when you could use `http.FileServer` to serve static content, and the fact that you read the whole response into a `[]byte` before sending it back instead of streaming it) but the *main* one is this:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, string(p))
```

`Fprintf`'s first argument is a *format string*. Replacing things in the format string that start with `%` is what it does. To write a `[]byte` to a writer you don't need the fmt package, because you don't want to format anything. [w.Write()](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) is good enough. `fmt.Fprint` is also available but completely unnecessary; it will do extra work that amounts to nothing and then call `w.Write`.

Comment: Downvoted for supercilious tone. Compare with nvcnvn's respectful and concise answer below.

Comment: @MikeEllis updated in light of nvcnvn's answer, which does a triple disservice to the OP by ignoring issues, making a poor recommendation, and failing to explain any reason behind the recommendation, just providing code without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `fmt.Fprintf` is interpreting the response body as a format string with % substitutions. One way to fix this is to supply a format string:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", p)
```

There's no need to convert `p` to a string with this approach.

The goal here is to write bytes to the response writer. The idiomatic and most efficient way to write bytes to a response writer (or any other io.Writer) is:

```
w.Write(p)
```

The `fmt` package is not appropriate to use here because no formatting is required.